# C# Append One DTO result to another DTO result

Tags: c#, linq, dto

I have two DTO classes in a C# MVC web app and I need to return a list generated from one class with a list of data generated by the second within the first list. (Think nested array eg [0[a,b], 1[a,b,c], 2[a,b,c,d], 3,[a], etc...])

This is for an internal application where staff members educate others about their job roles.

The following is what I have so far

```
        //Abstract code representative of end goal

        var foo = from x in _fooCtx.Foo
                     where (x.Condition1 && x.Condition2 && x.Condition3 && x.Condition4 > 0)
                     select new Models.ResourceDTO()
                     {
                         FirstName = x.FirstName,
                         LastName = x.LastName,
                         ResourceID = x.ResourceID,
                     };



        //currently loops through each memeber of staff in list above and grabs their wamits history.
        foreach (var foobar in foo)
        {
            int foobarID = foo.ResourceID;

            var bar = from u in _barCtx.BarViews
                                where (u.PupilID == foobarID || u.TeacherID == foobarID)
                                select new Models.ApplicationDTO()
                                {
                                    pupilName = u.Pupil,
                                    teacherName = u.Teacher,
                                    appDate = u.appDate.ToString(),
                                    appID = u.ID,

                                };

            var leaderList = bar.ToList();
        }
```

The above works fine in getting a list of active staff members and then looping through any previous sessions they may have done. I need to return the staff list where each member has the list generated by the second DTO select in the foreach loop. So a list of foo data and within this a list of bar data. If this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom DTO

```
Public class test
{
// add required properties along with list of ApplicationDTO 
// so it will be something like this (getter setters)

FirstName 

LastName

ResourceID

List<ApplicationDTO>
}
```

then you can create a list of this test class and use it

**P.S : this is just a sample example to help you understand how you can achieve this**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I don't think this is what I am looking for. I already have two separate DTO classes for both the resource and application. I need to append the results obtained in the foreach statement to the end of the to the results in the ResourceDTO select. So returning foo.ToList() will also contain the Application Data I need against each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union` for appending two dtos with the same type.

This will merge two dtos together:

```
 Dto1.Union(Dto2);
```